# call variable jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-function

[I've been shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14835803/1382306) how to call variable javascript `function`s by using `window[]()`.

Is it possible to call variable jQuery `function`s?  If so, how?

Usually, I only need a ternary to flip a visible switch, and it would be very convenient to smush many lines of code into 1.  For example, inside an `$.aja()` `success`:

```
if(msg.length > 0){
    $("#gridViewContainer").slideDown()
}
else{
    $("#gridViewContainer").slideUp()
}
```

This is probably a bad example since a `boolean` can probably be passed to `slide()` or something, but I'd like to use the concept in the linked question above.

This did not work for me:

```
$("#gridViewContainer")[((msg.length > 0)?'slideDown':'slideUp')]()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "call variable jQuery functions"? Could you give an example?

Comment: jQuery functions **are** javascript functions, since jQuery **is** javascript.

Comment: sure, `x="hide"; $(selector)[x]()`

Comment: @thg435 i tried that, and it doesn't work for some reason...

Comment: @Gracchus Post a fiddle that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qMtBj/

Comment: @Gracchus Here's (for the most part) your example working: http://jsfiddle.net/zavSb/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery functions are still just JavaScript functions, so the same rules apply to them as any other JS functions.

You can call methods of an object `objectVar` as follows:

```
objVar.method();
objVar["method"]();
var methodName = "method";
objVar[methodName]();
```

Your question mentioned using `window[]()` - that applies to global functions, since they are essentially properties of `window` (if running JS in the browser, of course).

In the case of jQuery, you can therefore do this:

```
var methodName = "hide";
$(someSelector)[methodName]();
$(someSelector)[anyJSExpressionThatReturnsAStringThatIsAjQueryMethod]();
```

EDIT: I just saw the new version of the question. The line of code shown with the `?:` operator selecting the method name should give the same effect as the `if/else`. I've used similar code myself with no problems, and it works fine in [the fiddle that Jason P provided](http://jsfiddle.net/zavSb/). Note that since your motivation here seems to be about making the code shorter you can omit all of the parentheses from the expression in the `[]` and just do this:

```
$("#gridViewContainer")[msg.length > 0?'slideDown':'slideUp']();
```

...or even omit the `> 0` part since `msg.length` will be truthy when non-zero:

```
$("#gridViewContainer")[msg.length ?'slideDown':'slideUp']();
```